# Unable to run a .bat file in java program

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, cmd, selenium-grid2

Problem Statement: I just want to start the HUB and Node to perform some tests using Selenium Grid.
I have two Batch files START HUB.bat and START NODE.bat which run perfectly when i manually run them.
But i want them to run using a Java Program @BeforeMethod.
I looked for answers

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start \"./BatchFiles/START HUB.bat\"");
```

This Opens Up the CMD but goes to the path of my .git project but doesnt run the bat file.

I tried using Process Builder but that doesn't open the cmd.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C"," start", "START HUB.bat");
    File dir = new File("D:\\work\\GIT REPOSITORY\\project.selenium.maven.jenkinsCI\\BatchFiles");
    pb.directory(dir);
    Process p = pb.start();
```

Can someone please help me with this issue. Below are the commands in the batch file.

```
    D:
    cd work
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub
```

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path to the batch file (not using a relative path ./BatchFiles/...).  Directory separators on Windows are backslash, but your first example shows wrong separator.

Comment: Can you try with Absolute path of the batch file? Rename the batch file such that there is no space inbetween. To check, is the content in batch file is correct, try running it manually.

Comment: batch file runs perfectly fine manually. I used the absolute path as well.

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "cmd /C start \"D:\\work\\GIT REPOSITORY\\project.selenium.maven.jenkinsCI\\BatchFiles\\START_HUB.bat\"");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to execute the command line:

```
cmd /C start "./BatchFiles/START HUB.bat"
```

With `cmd` at beginning of the command line a new command process is already started with executing `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`. This command process should automatically close after running the command as explicitly requested with option `/C` which means **close** as it can be read on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`.

The command to execute in this command process is:

```
start "./BatchFiles/START HUB.bat"
```

The internal command `start` of `cmd.exe` is for starting an executable or script in a new process. Its help can be read on running in a command prompt window `start /?`.

The first double quoted string is interpreted by `start` as title of the new command process window opened when a batch file or a console application should be executed in a new command process.

And this is the reason why the batch file is not executed because `"./BatchFiles/START HUB.bat"` is interpreted as window title string.

And on Windows the directory separator is `\` and not `/` as on Unix. `/` is used as begin of an option as you can see on `/C`. But Windows handles also file paths with `/` often correct because of replacing each `/` internally by `\` in directory/file names with an absolute or relative path on accessing the directory or file.

So the solution is using either

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start \"start hub\" \".\\BatchFiles\\START HUB.bat\"");
```

or using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C \"BatchFiles\\START HUB.bat\"");
```

A path starting with a directory or file name is relative to current directory of the running process on Windows like using `.\` at begin of a directory or file name string.

The first code starts a command process which executes the command `start` which starts one more command process with title `start hub` executing the batch file. The first command process started with `cmd.exe` immediately terminates after running `start` while the batch file is executed in second started command process. This means your Java application continues while the batch file is executed parallel.

The second code results in executing the batch file in the single command process started with `cmd.exe` and halting the execution of the Java application until entire batch file execution finished.

The usage of a batch file can be removed here by using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start \"start hub\" /D D:\\work java.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub");
```

With `/D D:\work` the working **directory** is defined for the command process started for executing `java.exe` with its parameters.

Alternatively without using `start` command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C cd /D D:\\work && java.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub");
```

Run in a command prompt window `cd /?` for help on `cd /D D:\work` and see [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&&` used here to specify two commands to execute on one line whereby `java.exe` is executed only if `cd` could successfully change the working directory to `D:\work`.

Comment: The below code really worked

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start \"start hub\" \".\\BatchFiles\\START_HUB.bat\"");

Answer (score 0):

```
class RunFile
{
    public static void main(String[] arg){

        Runtime runtime = null;
        try{
            runtime.getRuntime.exec("cmd /C start \"D:\\work\\GIT REPOSITORY\\project.selenium.maven.jenkinsCI\\BatchFilesmyBatchFile.bat\\START HUB.bat\"");   
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Did you try to pass the absolute path to the `exec` function?
As well as quote the path since you're having a whitespace between `START` and `HUB`

Comment: Yes i have tried with the absolute path and the name of the bat file is START HUB..that contains a white space. Can you tell me the if the contents for the batch file is correct?

Comment: The statements inside your batch file seems to be correct - nothings wrong with them! If it's possible you could rename the batch file to something which doesn't include white spaces? (I'm still thinking that this is the issue)

Comment: Tried renaming the batch file to START_NODE.bat. Still the same issue. The cmd just opens with the path 

        D:\work\GIT REPOSITORY\project.selenium.maven.jenkinsCI>

Comment: Did you use `cmd /C \"D:\\work\\GIT REPOSITORY\\project.selenium.maven.jenkinsCI\\BatchFilesmyBatchFile.bat\\START HUB.bat\"` to achieve this?

Comment: the solution by @Mofi worked perfectly. Dint need the absolute path.

         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start \"start hub\" \".\\BatchFiles\\START_HUB.bat\"");

Answer (score 0):

The explanation by @Mofi really helped here understanding as to how cmd treats each and every "/".

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start \"start hub\" \".\\BatchFiles\\START HUB.bat\"");
```

Above is the solution that worked for me.